# Escaping special characters batch for loop

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a loop that iterates on a text file where I have several file paths on each line.

The goal is to iterate throw file paths and copy them to a different location.

I’m not a windows beast (pref UNIX) but managed to make it works:

```
@echo off
For /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('type file_list.txt') do xcopy /hrkvy "%%a" "S:\dest_dir"
```

The paths in the .txt are full path pointing to some files. There is one path every line. The final result is a script that should copy files stored elsewhere on the computer right to the location I launched the script.

The issue is that some paths contain characters like single quotes which make my code to not work. Here is an example of the file_list.txt:

```
C:\temp\path with single quote ' - 1.txt   // doesn't work
C:\temp\path without single quote - 2.txt  // work
C:\temp\path with single quote ' - 3.txt   // doesn't work
```

However it doesn’t work for paths that contain special characters. It's possible that some characters other than single quote are causing issues to. I have no idea how to scape those characters from a loop. Any idea?

Comment: a single quote `'` doesn't need any escaping. It's just a char. If it "doesn't work" (what's the error message?), it's not a `'`.

Comment: it says file not found.

Comment: It just works, even your own code works with your sample file, without problems! Probably there are hidden spaces at the line end or the file simply doesn't exist. Or the minus sign is copied from msWord and therefore it isn't a real minus sign

Comment: Are you sure, the actual file names use `'`? It might be some other similar looking char.

Comment: Problem is: I copy the paths that don't work with my code in the files explorer path field and it works.

Comment: I've just found that it doesn't work with letters with punctuation like 'É'.

Comment: or characters like Î...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem description is missing too many information.
Without showing a sample file or explain which special characters, do you think, are problematic, it's hard to guess what the real problem is.

But the only problematic special characters in such a case, when using `"%%a"`, a quoted for meta variable, are the exclamation mark `!` and the caret `^`, but only when you have delayed expansion enabled!
You can get more problems, if your paths are surrounded by quotes itself.

But modifying it a bit, should solve any problems.

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
For /f "delims=" %%a in (file_list.txt) do (
  xcopy /hrkvy "%%~a" "S:\dest_dir"
)
```

Comment: I tried to explain with more details my issue as I can't show the .txt here.

Comment: Even if you can't show your file, you should be able to show a minimal file with dummy paths like `C:\temp\my problematic special char.txt`. What error message you get? Do  you use Unicode/language specific characters or do you try to use  `:|?*` inside your path? Without information your question is useless